# How to make alive nohup process?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, nohup

I am using the `nohup` command with Python and Flask for background process. After I close the terminal it is working fine but after 1 or 2 days the process stops. Can someone tell me how to keep the background process running? I am using below command:

```
screen
space
nohup python -m flask run --cert local.crt --key local.key --host=0.0.0.0 --port=443 &
ctrl+a+d
```

Comment: I suggest you run Flask for two days without nohup to see if it causes an error of some sort.

Comment: You should probably use a property daemon, like gunicorn, for this purpose.

Comment: @KenKinder please can you explain in detail how to use daemon like gunicorn

Comment: I would recommend using something like a `systemctl` service for such purposes which provide additional support of auto-restarting your service in case it crashes or fails and making sure that it keeps running

Comment: `nohup` does not run the process in the background. It simply makes it ignore the `HUP` signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume all your Flask code resides in the folder `/home/abc_user/flask_app`.

### Steps

1. Create a file `flask-server.service` in `/etc/systemd/system`.

   ```
    [Unit]
    Description=Flask server
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    User=abc_user
    Group=abc_user
    WorkingDirectory=/home/abc_user/flask_app
    ExecStart=python -m flask run --cert local.crt --key local.key --host=0.0.0.0 --port=443
    Restart=always

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.
3. Start the service using `systemctl start flask-server.service`.
4. Check that it has started by `systemctl status flask-server.service`. Status should say "running".
5. If you want your flask server to auto-start after reboots, run `systemctl enable flask-server.service`

#### Some common operations

1. Check current status - `systemctl status flask-server.service`
2. Start the service - `systemctl start flask-server.service`
3. Stop the service - `systemctl stop flask-server.service`
4. Check logs - `journalctl -u flask-server.service`
5. Stream logs - `journalctl -f -u flask-server.service`
6. Check logs in past 1 hour - `journalctl -u flask-server.service --since "1 hour ago"`

Comment: Thanks.I am getting error /etc/systemd/system/flask-server.service:9: Executable "python" not found in path "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/ when I run - `systemctl status flask-server.service`

Comment: Replace `python` by output of `which python`

Comment: Previous error has been resolved.Now I am getting error `Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/flask-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-01-05 17:37:19 UTC; 5s ago
    Process: 1418725 ExecStart=/usr/bin/which python -m flask run --cert local.crt --key local.key --host=0.0.0.0 --port=443 (code=exited, status=217/USER)
   Main PID: 1418725 (code=exited, status=217/USER)`

Comment: It says `(code=exited, status=217/USER)` which means that the user does not exist or you might have made some mistakes when adding it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176240/how-to-debug-a-failed-systemctl-service-code-exited-status-217-user)

Comment: Now I am getting error `Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/flask-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-01-05 19:05:37 UTC; 5s ago
    Process: 1419532 ExecStart=/usr/bin/which python -m flask run --cert local.crt --key local.key --host=0.0.0.0 --port=443 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1419532 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Comment: Please check logs via `journalctl` command mentioned in the question and share them. One issue that I see is that you have written python path as `/usr/bin/which python` instead of the output of `which python` which returns `/usr/bin/python` on my system. So I would replace `/usr/bin/which python` by `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226890/discussion-between-martin-and-amit-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Try `nohup python -m flask run --cert local.crt --key local.key --host=0.0.0.0 --port=443 >/dev/null 2>&1&`
Use  `nohup` , you should redirct you print to `/dev/null` or `log`, Otherwise it will be create a file `nohup.out` occupy disk space.

Most times we use `gunicorn` and `supervisor` to manager flask application.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use gunicorn in flask.

Comment: `pip install gunicorn` then run `gunicorn -d -b 0.0.0.0:443 --certfile=local.crt --keyfile=local.key  [app_file:app_name]`

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe shut down the computer the flask server is running on ?
If so, the problem will be solved by either not shutting down your computer or starting the flask server again after shutting down !

Answer (score 0):

nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout.

Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called **nohup.out** if it has not already been redirected.

See **nohup.out** for searching errors in ./ or executed directory. It is no **nohup** error. Look nohup.out and google error and will refresh question.